# Combine Jersey with Tyrus

Tags: websocket, jersey, jax-rs, grizzly, tyrus

I have a Jersey JAX-RS application which runs on a Grizzly instance:

```
public class Application {
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("my.package.rest");
        HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
        System.out.println("Server started, press any key to stop.");
        System.in.read();
        server.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

inside `my.package.rest` there are JAX-RS annotated resources. I'd like to add websocket annotated (`@ServerEndpoint`, `@OnOpen`, `@OnMessage`, etc.) resources using Tyrus on the same server instance (say in "http://127.0.0.1:8080/websocket") but all the documentation I was able to find shows how to start a standalone websocket server using Tyrus + a Grizzly container, not combined with Jersey. I'm looking for something like:

```
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new SomeTyrusHttpHandler("/websocket"));
```

but I can't find anything similar to `SomeTyrusHttpHandler`. How can I combine Jersey and Tyrus in a single Grizzly server?

Answer (score 1):

good question, but there is currently no good answer for this one. You still can do that, but it would require to deep dive into Grizzly internals; Tyrus is registered by an addon (see [WebSocketAddOn](https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/blob/8fa37c8ea22d012606c426aff75b8e801bc315bd/containers/grizzly-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/tyrus/container/grizzly/server/WebSocketAddOn.java)) and it can be combined with Jersey way of registering into that container.

Please have in mind that integrating these two frameworks together is not trivial challenge - running them in a single container is a first step, but there are other things which need to be taken care of, like "instance provider", lifecycle adjustment, etc. I believe this topic exceeds the scope of one SO answer - you can expect blogpost from me or some other Tyrus/Jersey team member about this. (I'll post it here once that is done).

Anyway, I would recommend to take more conservative approach and use some lightweight container which supports Servlet 3.1; that should require far less work on your side and you'll have standard Servlet runtime / lifecycle.

Comment: Just use Atmosphere, it does exactly what you want and allow to run Jersey on top of Grizzly, GlassFish etc. https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere. For example http://goo.gl/s7OwGc is super easy example of Jersey 2 running transparently on top of websockets.

Comment: see https://github.com/pavelbucek/placeholder -- PoC, which combines Jersey and Tyrus (on top of Grizzly + HK2).

Comment: Hello, is there any news of such an integration? I would like to add a WebSocket resource to my Jersey project.